# Angular NgTagsInputs - RegEx - Allow all values expect Strings

Tags: angularjs, regex, regex-negation

I'm using [ngTagsInput](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/) where I want to allow all tags expect a few strings.

In their documentation it appears I can specify allowed tags through a regex but I can seem to work it out - been trying http://regexr.com/ for last hour with no luck.

So for example the strings I dont want to be accepted are:

`story` and `global`.

How do i go about to say everything is allowed expect those 2?

So for example `storyBreaking` is allowed but `story` is not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try something like that:
`(?<![\w\d])abc(?![\w\d])` where *abc* is your string to match!

Comment: That negative look around doesnt appear to be supported by JS - so i used `^(?![\w\d])abc(?![\w\d])` but that doesnt work